# run time error while working with Orchard cms 1.10.1

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I defined a content type and defined a content item, all from admin panel not code.

I get this run time error when clicking on content in admin panel.

How can I deal with this error?

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the      current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set  to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 71:                 // Throwing a TIE here will probably kill the web    process
Line 72:                 // in Azure. For unknown reasons.
Line 73:                 throw e.InnerException;
Line 74:             }
Line 75:         }

Source File: E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs    Line: 73 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
          Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.PerformInvoke(DisplayContext displayContext, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object serviceInstance) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:73
 Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateDelegate>b__0(DisplayContext context) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:55
  Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass7_1. <BoundAs>b__1(DisplayContext displayContext) in E:\Orchard development\Projects  1.10.1\Animal  Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
     Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:204
 Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:100
 Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
 Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name,  INamedEnumerable`1 parameters) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal  Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:44
      Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder  binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in E:\Orchard development\Projects  1.10.1\Animal  Support\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:29
 CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +193
 ASP._Page_Core_Contents_Views_Admin_List_cshtml.Execute() in e:\Orchard  development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal    Support\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Contents\Views\Admin\List.cshtml:68
 System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
 System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
 System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext      pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
 System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
 System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext,  TextWriter writer) +107
 Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.<>c__DisplayClass9_0. <FindView>b__0(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer  viewDataContainer) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal  Support\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:59
 Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.LayoutView.Render(ViewContext  viewContext, TextWriter writer) in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal  Support\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:90
 System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
```

System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
     System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
     System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
     System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
     System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
     System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
     System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
     System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
     System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) +72
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
     Orchard.Mvc.Routes.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:182
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
   Orchard.Owin.<b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\Owin\OrchardMiddleware.cs:17
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.d__5.MoveNext() in E:\Orchard development\Projects 1.10.1\Animal Support\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:189
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
     System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +71
     System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +11
     System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9644037
     System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: You should probably file a bug.

Comment: It happened after i added a image field to my content type ( it already had some content items defined). I removed the content type entirly and defined it again and it got fixed.

Comment: You should still file a bug ;) Seems like you have a good repro.

Comment: Couldn't repro the bug in a refresh build so i guess i leave it for now